# True or False? If A is invertible, then the inverse of its Hermitian transpose is the Hermitian transpose of the inverse of A.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is invertible, then the inverse of its Hermitian transpose is the 
      Hermitian transpose of the inverse of $A$, i.e $(A^H)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^H$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: so far I think the statement is true, and I can find out that when A is a real matrix let's say <<1,2>|<3,4>> this statement does hold, but how can I prove it in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $AA^{-1}=I$. What do you get if you taken the Hermitian transpose of both sides of this equation. What is another way of writing $(AA^{-1})^H$ ? What is $I^H$ ?

Comment: Thanks! I think i got it.